# Comparing random effects intercepts of two independent subjects

Tags: regression, mixed-model, regression-coefficients, random-effects-model

Are the random effects intercepts of two independent subjects comparable in a mixed model?

For example, lets say I have this model:

`mod = lmer(y ~ x + (1|S1) + (1|S2))`

Could I compare one of the S1 random effects to an S2 effect? I don't think so, but wanted to make sure.